# jqGrid pager buttons overlapping with the arrow buttons

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am adding few of my own buttons on the jgGrid pager. I am also increasing the width of the grid to window width (in loadComplete). As I increase the width, the the pagination control (move first, move last, text box, etc) does not remain at the center. It moves to the left and overlaps the buttons. Please refer to the screenshot below. Thanks

[image: Pagination overlapping]

Comment: Please share the code in loadComplete()

Comment: loadComplete:function(){
 jQuery(gridName).setGridWidth(jQuery(window).width(),true);
}

Answer (score 0):

Probably the reason is the *initial* width of the grid which you use at the creation of jqGrid. I would recommend you to experiment with the value of `width` parameter which you use at the creating of jqGrid. Alternatively you can consider to change the width of `#pager_center` (middle part of the grid pager) or `#pager_left` and `#pager_right`.

Answer (score 0):

For overlapping I would suggest using **navSeparatorAdd** after each nav button (**navButtonAdd**).

```
.navSeparatorAdd("#pager",{separator_parameters}
```

`separator_parameters ==> sepclass : "ui-separator", sepcontent: "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"` if you want to create a seperator of three spaces.